# Can I use iOS' local pushnotification in OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to get iOS' Local PushNotification to work on OSX? I have an program that I would like to receive scheduled notifications from the local computer even if the program is closed.

Comment: I think that you know the answer just by how you phrased that question... That being said, search for "user notifications + mountain lion" and you should find some more information

Answer (score 0):

This is for local notification

```
 - (void)scheduleNotificationWithItem:(ToDoItem *)item interval:(int)minutesBefore {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    [dateComps setDay:item.day];

    [dateComps setMonth:item.month];

    [dateComps setYear:item.year];

    [dateComps setHour:item.hour];

    [dateComps setMinute:item.minute];

    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

    [dateComps release];



    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    if (localNotif == nil)

        return;

    localNotif.fireDate = [itemDate addTimeInterval:-(minutesBefore*60)];

    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];



    localNotif.alertBody =@"Local Notification";

    localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);



    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;



    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:item.eventName forKey:ToDoItemKey];

    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;



    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

    [localNotif release];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is here : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications

Comment: those notifications are sent immediately and I think the program has to be open to recieve them.

Comment: It's easy to make a faceless application starting with the mac and looking for notifications, holding them until a spefific application started (another notification by the way) Anyway there's  also NSNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold
The server holds all matching notifications until the queue has been filled (queue size determined by the server) at which point the server may flush queued notifications.